# Reload same level but retaining Player Object in libGdx

Tags: libgdx

I've been working with libGdx for a University project on a roguelite game.
The basic idea is you have one room, clear the enemies, and when you use the door, you respawn in the same level, but with stronger enemies.
The thing is, i need to preserve the player stats for the course of the game without erasing it when i reload the level again.

I've been trying to look into Scenes, but was wondering is there is an specific way to basicaly reload the rending but leaving the player object untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot to go on, much would depend on how you've structured/coded your game. But a simplistic approach could be to indeed have a Player class, which contains say an Image (Actor) and a Stats member object (or however you keep track of stats). Instantiate one Player Object and keep updating its stats for the duration of your game, they won't go away.

Your Image (subclass of Actor - again, simplistic), could have your Player's drawable for rendering. If your level is always the same, you could use the same Stage to contain your level's Actors (players, enemies, whatever). You can add/remove Actors from the Stage, thus creating different levels.

But your Player class doesn't have to go anywhere. It is only the Player's Image (Actor) that might add/leave a level (Stage). The Player class would still contain the stats and any other attributes you need about your Player.